# R shiny calling (observer builder) functions in source context

Tags: r, function, shiny

Here's a sample code:

```
library("shiny")

createObserver <- function(id) {
  observeEvent(input[[id]], {
    message(paste("button", id, "pushed"))
  })
}

ui <- actionButton("foo", "bar")

server <- function(input, output) {
  createObserver("foo")
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

This code complains about `Warning: Error in observeEventExpr: object 'input' not found`. I could theoretically pass the `input` variable as a function argument (what I plan to do right now), but that juggling with function arguments (`input`, `output`, `session`) feels really messy.

Is there no other way then to pass all those runtime variables as arguments to builder functions like these?

What is the best practice when dealing with shiny builder functions?

EDIT:

I guess I really have to pass input, output and any potential reactiveValue object to the function.

Answer (score 2):

I think that the mess is using **input** out of the server, try this instead:

```
library("shiny")
ui <- actionButton("foo", "bar")

server <- function(input, output) {
  createObserver <- function(id) {
    observeEvent(input[[id]], {
      message(paste("button", id, "pushed"))
    })
  }
  createObserver("foo")
}
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

The clue here is to put your function inside the server.
Hope it help

Comment: Unfortunately, it looks like the function has to be defined in a global context.